# How to jump directly to the problem showed by the visual studio code warning?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: warning in vs code]

Hi guys

I'd like to know how can i jump directly to the warning showed by vs code ?

thanks!

Comment: use the PROBLEMS panel

Comment: With editor focus try `F8`.